# My account reset?

Tags: steam, macos, arma-2

I made my own steam account back in 2016 and I purchased a game called "Arma 2"...I had no trouble playing this game on my laptop that I made the account with and brought the games with also.

But, unfortunately I had broken that laptop as it fell on my wooden floor  by accident and I tried taking it to the shop they told me that they couldn't fix it, so I brought an mac computer and I tried logging back in and it went through the code process and email verification but when I logged in and checked my games it was empty...

So I searched up the game I brought and I was hoping that I wouldn't have to buy it again but I clicked on the game and It said I have to buy it again??? I also brought an game on this mac that was not compatible with this computer so I have gotten it refunded, just wanted to know if that was the problem???

Please help as I really don't want to purchase all the games again!

Comment: I just really need help at the moment, I don't want to lose any of my games as I love steam and it's network of games.

Comment: You should explain this to Steam.  They could tell you whether your account has ever owned that game.  If not, presumably you recovered the wrong account.  They can help you find the right one.  If it does have the game or once did, they can tell you why it is not available.  We could only speculate on those things.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, ARMA 2 doesn't support macOS, it's windows only:

[image]

To see if you're on the correct account, first hover over "Library" and pick "Games":

[image]

After you do that, you should be able to see your games.

If you can't, then you probably logged into a wrong account and should try to remember the correct email and password.

Comment: I purchased this game on a windows 10 laptop... I know that the compatibility is not with the mac I just want to make sure all my games are there as I am going to buy an windows PC soon.

Comment: @RITIK_GAMES_YT did you try going to the games tab as it's displayed in the second picture?